# Different types of result for np.where .The x,y are interchanged in the two conditions. What am I missing?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I'm trying to initialize two arrays *image* and *a*.

In *image* I'm filling the contours with color value 255
in the contours *cnt* which is in the order x,y.

And in *a* array I'm assigning the value 1 for a[2][0] .where 2 is the x-axis point and 0 is the y-axis point.

But in the result I'm getting the order for image in y array ,x array but in a it is x array , y array .

Where am I making the mistake ???

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros((700,700),dtype=np.int32)
cnt = np.array([[340, 157], [695, 157], [695, 309], [340, 309], [340, 157]])

image = cv2.fillPoly(image,[cnt],color=255)

a = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=np.int32)
a [2][0] = 1

print(np.where(a>0)) #output_1
print(np.where(image>0)) #output_2
```

**output_1**:
(array([2]), array([0]))

**output_2**:
(array([157, 157, 157, ..., 309, 309, 309]), array([340, 341, 342, ..., 693, 694, 695]))

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake with the code. I have rewritten this using numpy slices to fill up portions of the array.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = np.zeros((700,700),dtype=np.int32)
print(image.shape)
# cnt = np.array([[340, 157], [695, 157], [695, 309], [340, 309], [340, 157]])
image[157:309, 340:695] = 255

# image = cv2.fillPoly(image,[cnt],color=255)
print(image.shape)

a = np.zeros((10,10),dtype=np.int32)
a [2, 0:5] = 1

print(np.where(a>0)) #output_1
print(np.where(image==255)) #output_2
```

```
(array([2], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64))
(array([157, 157, 157, ..., 308, 308, 308], dtype=int64), array([340, 341, 342, ..., 692, 693, 694], dtype=int64))
```

If you look at this, `image[157:309, 340:695] = 255`
the slice along the x-axis is described by columns, and y-axis slice by rows.
The cnt part of your code, describes a range of rows from 157-309, and a range of columns from 340-695 and thats why the output.

Comment: I got it thanks. x is the column and y is the rows .So in the output it is (rows,columns) i,e (y array,x array ) .And by the cnt is the polygon([x,y] points) i dont think so it can filled by slicing.